# Все маркеры гугл-карты сливаются в одну точку

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, карты

При вставке кода гугл-карты с множеством маркеров все маркеры сливаются в одну точку.

Мой код:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1xlUDJx8apgaZcI2mPAk1Rc9OgyHwEfqo" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Результат на сайте (вкладка "участники"):
https://test.chess22barnaul.ru/federation/projects/

Что делаю неправильно? как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте параметр приближения на карте z

Например

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1xlUDJx8apgaZcI2mPAk1Rc9OgyHwEfqo&z=6" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде помогло!